# Number of multiples with equal modulo

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I am working on a computer hardware modeling project and have come across an interesting math problem that I don't know how to solve:

Given integers $E$ and $W$, consider $S$ as the set of all values $(cE) \text{ mod } W$, for all $c$ integers from 0 to $W$.  Whats the maximum number of values in $S$ that are equal?

It seems that if $E$ and $W$ are co-prime, the answer is 1.  However, I don't know how to determine this for an arbitrary $E$ and $W$.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: If $E,W$ are co-prime you might say $\gcd(E,W) = 1$

Comment: have you looked up the Chinese remainder theorem or about modular remainders in arithmetic progressions. ?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\gcd(E,W) = g$, i.e. $E = g e$ and $W = g w$ where $e$ and $w$ are coprime.
Then the following are equivalent:
$$\eqalign{c E &\equiv c' E \mod W\cr
 g w &\mid\; (c - c') g e \cr
 w &\mid\; (c - c') e\cr
 w &\mid\; c - c'\cr
c &\equiv c' \mod w\cr}$$
If $c \in \{0,1,\ldots, W\}$, there are $g$ values $c' = c + t w$ such that $c \equiv c' \mod w$.